# Link is redirecting for Root instead of controller show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to use `link_to` for redirect for selections show page.
But when I click this link it redirect to root page.

I tried different ways, but it always redirects to index root.

```
<%= link_to 'Detalhes', selection %>
```

I also tried:

```
<%= link_to 'Detalhes', selection_path(selection) %>
<%= link_to 'Detalhes', selection, :method => :show %> 
<%= link_to 'Detalhes', selection, method: :show %>
```

And, in `routes.rb`:

```
match '/selections/:id' => 'selections#show', :via => :post
```

Routes, if need that:

```
 selections GET    /selections(.:format)                                   selections#index
                     POST   /selections(.:format)                                   selections#create
       new_selection GET    /selections/new(.:format)                               selections#new
      edit_selection GET    /selections/:id/edit(.:format)                          selections#edit
           selection GET    /selections/:id(.:format)                               selections#show
                     PUT    /selections/:id(.:format)                               selections#update
                     DELETE /selections/:id(.:format)                               selections#destroy
```

My log when i try access a selection:

```
Started GET "/selections/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-21 09:34:55 -0300
Processing by SelectionsController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
[1m[35mSelection Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "selections".* FROM "selections" WHERE     "selections"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mRole Load (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "roles_users" ON "roles"."id" = "roles_users"."role_id" WHERE "roles_users"."user_id" = 2 AND "roles"."name" = 'Administrator' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mRole Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "roles_users" ON "roles"."id" = "roles_users"."role_id" WHERE "roles_users"."user_id" = 2 AND "roles"."name" = 'TeamMaster' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mRole Load (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "roles_users" ON "roles"."id" = "roles_users"."role_id" WHERE "roles_users"."user_id" = 2 AND "roles"."name" = 'Team' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "selections".* FROM "selections" WHERE "selections"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", "1"]]
  Rendered selections/show.html.erb within layouts/application (1.7ms)
Redirected to http:// localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 34ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: You can't have this line `match '/selections/:id' => 'selections#show', :via => :post` because it doesn't show in your routes (or you didn't include it). This line itself makes no sense because how you expect the app to show something on POST request?

Comment: And in this line `<%= link_to 'Detalhes', selection %>` what do you pass as `selection`?

Comment: You're right Michael Szyndel, it was just a desperate try.
And in <%= link_to 'Detalhes', selection %>, selection is a list of all selections indexed, result of @selections.each do |selection|

Comment: Have you checked the filters? Maybe some filter redirects the requests. Please check the log.

Answer (score 0):

the correct implementation is to have:

in your ***routes.rb***

`resources :selections`

in your views

`link_to 'The text', selection`

The things to verify are:

- You restarted your server after you changed route.rb, otherwise it wont catch it up
- In your view check the HREF of your link if its correct
- After clicking check your rails console to see if there is no redirection

Comment: Hi, i forgot one thing:

In routes.rb i have tried "resources :selections" and not worked.
After i tried "match '/selections/:id' => 'selections#show', :via => :post" and i get same result.

So, apparently, the route in routes.rb is not the problem.

Comment: what's the generated href?